how to compute the rate of deformation gradient in finite-element context?
I am implementing hyper visco-elastic material models similar to those from Pioletti et al. see here
There, a viscous potential, e.g
$W_v = \eta [I_1-3]J_2 \quad \text{with} \quad J_2 = \mathrm{tr}(\dot{\mathbf{C}^2})$
is defined depending on strain rate invariants of the right Cauchy-Green tensor $\mathbf{C}$. The viscous stress reads
$\mathbf{S}_v = 2\frac{\partial W_v}{\partial \dot{\mathbf{C}}}$
and is added to the elastic stresses derived from a strain energy function, e.g. Neo-Hooke.
To implement such models in a FE-environment, one has to come up with an approximation of $\dot{\mathbf{C}}$.
In a typical non-linear FE-solver, there is a loop over (pseudo) load steps, with inner Newton-Raphson iteration loops. In the literature, I only came across finite-difference approaches of the form
$\dot{\mathbf{C}} = \frac{\mathbf{C}^n_k - \mathbf{C}^{n-1}}{\Delta t}$
where $\mathbf{C}^n_k$ is the current right Cauchy Green tensor (@load step n and Newton iteration k), $\mathbf{C}^{n-1}$ is the right Cauchy Green tensor at the previous converged load step, and $\Delta t$ is the size of the load step.
This approximation leads to $J_2 = 0$ in the first Newton iteration of any load step since the current solution is equal to the previous solution which is clearly not physical.
Are there alternative approaches to approximate $\dot{\mathbf{C}}$?
Any recommendations or references are appreciated.
UPDATE:
Based on the comment from Wolfgang Bangerth, I added some deal.ii pseudo code.
Vector<double> solution_delta (n_dofs);

Vector<double> solution_n (n_dofs);
Vector<double> solution_n-1 (n_dofs);

while (time.current() < time.end())
{
    solution_delta = 0.0;
    solve_nonlinear_timestep(solution_delta);
    solution_n += solution_delta;
    solution_n-1 = solution_n;
    time.increment();
}

void 
solve_nonlinear_timestep(Vector<double>  &solution_delta)
{
    Vector<double> newton_update(n_dofs);

    for (/** Loop over Newton iterations */)
    {
          Vector<double> solution_curr = solution_n + solution_delta;
          assemble_system( solution_curr );
          solve_linear_system(newton_update);
          ...
          solution_delta += newton_update;
    }
}

// Inside assemble_system(), I calculate
   - C_curr ( from solution_curr)
   - C_n-1 ( from solution_n-1) --> this is constant in the entire time steps
   - C_dot = C_curr - C_n-1 / \Delta T


You could try tracking $\dot{C}$ between real timesteps to see if it will converge to the same solution faster. Then in the first iteration you can compute $C^n_k$ using $\dot{C}_0$.

What do you mean by tracking \dot{\mathbf{C}}? And what do you refer to as \dot{\mathbf{C}}_0? The issue that J_2 = 0 occurs in the first iteration at every load step, not only in the first load step.

Save the value of $\dot{C}$ as $\dot{C}_0$ between load steps, then for the first iteration choose your guess for $C^1_k = \Delta t \dot{C}_0 + C^{0}$. This may or may not work better, and of course won't fix the very first load step unless you prescribe an initial guess for $\dot{C}$.

It may not necessarily be a problem for $J_2 = 0$ for the first iteration if that's what your references are using, especially since this is in the Newton iteration while a consistent non-linear solution has not been found yet. This is usually only problematic if you end up with something mathematically ill-defined, like division by zero or introducing a critical point which might impact convergence. I don't know enough about the properties of the entire system you're trying to solve to say one way or the other.

Oh, I think I mixed up the indices. It would be $C^n_0 = \dot{C}^{n-1} \Delta t + C^{n-1}$, then you can continue with the regular iteration for $k > 0$.

I also thought in that direction that $J_2=0$ at the beginning is not a real problem as long as the load step converges. What worries me more (I have not mentioned it in my question) is the missing property of quadratic convergence. A short question in this regard: When we do a finite difference approximation of $\dot{\mathbf{C}}$ like in my question, can we say $\frac{\partial \mathbf{C}}{\partial \dot{\mathbf{C}}} = 0$ ? In that case, most of the terms of the tangent operator $\frac{\partial \mathbf{S}_v}{\partial  \dot{\mathbf{C}} }$  vanish.

If you're already running a Newton iteration, why not treat $C=C(u)$ with the to-be-computed displacement of the current time step, and then use $\dot C = \frac{C(u)-C^{n-1}}{\Delta t}$?

@WolfgangBangerth This is exactly what I am doing. In your notation $\mathbf{C}(\mathbf{u})$ is the current right Cauchy Green tensor (as of course computed from the current solution $\mathbf{u}$) and $\mathbf{C}^{n-1}$ is the right Cauchy Green tensor from the load step before (as computed from the solution $\mathbf{u}^{n-1}$ at the load step before). But this naturally leads to $\dot{\mathbf{C}} = 0$ in the first Newton itereation since there the current solution is the same as the one from the load step before. Did you refer to something else?

@WolfgangBangerth Can you maybe also comment on the derivative $\frac{\partial \mathbf{C}}{\partial \dot{\mathbf{C}}}$ if we do the finite difference approximation like shown by you? Is this derivative zero? At the moment, I have a very bad convergence rate in the Newton iterations and I can not solve any problems. Since I do not have quadratic convergence, I suspect there are missing terms in the tangent operator which I build under the assumption $\frac{\partial \mathbf{C}}{\partial \dot{\mathbf{C}}} = 0$.

No, $C(u)$ is not computed from the current solution. It is computed from the to-be-computed solution of the current Newton step.

@WolfgangBangerth I added some deal.ii pseudo code to have more space to clarify my thoughts. Not sure what you mean by "C(u) is not computed from the current solution. It is computed from the to-be computed solution of the current Newton step". Is the above pseudo code not calculating $\dot{\mathbf{C}}$ as you suggested?

The truth is that I don't actually know very much about this, and so this may or may not be at all helpful. But let me sort my thoughts in the following way:
Let's say for simplicity that you're trying to find a root of the residual
$$
  F(u) = 0
$$
where in reality the form of $F(u)$ is of the form
$$
  F(u) = F(u, C(u), \dot C(u)).
$$
Let's say you've already computed Newton iteration $k$ in time step $n$ (as in your original post), then you can approximate
$$
  \dot C(u) \approx \dot C_\text{fixed} = \frac{ C(u^n_k) - C(u^{n-1})}{\Delta t}
$$
(where the right hand side does not depend on $u$, only on the previous iteration's solution),
and put that into the form for $F$, but if you do that then the derivative with regard to $u$ (i.e., the Newton matrix you will have to form) is going to be
$$
J_k = \nabla_u F(u^n_k) = \left[\frac{\partial F(u,C,\dot C_\text{fixed})}{\partial u} + 
\frac{\partial F}{\partial C(u,C,\dot C_\text{fixed})} + \frac{\partial F(u,C,\dot C_\text{fixed})}{\partial \dot C}\right]_{u=u^n_k, C=C(u^n_k), \dot C=\dot C(u^n_k)}
$$
but the last term in brackets is zero because you've fixed the $\dot C_\text{fixed}$ argument and the derivative with regard to $\dot C$ is zero.
A better way to do this is not to fix $\dot C$ and instead use
$$
  \dot C(u) \approx \frac{ C(u) - C(u^{n-1})}{\Delta t}
$$
in which case the last term in square brackets may be nonzero (depending on the form of $F$).
In that case, you will also have
$$
\frac{\partial C(u)}{\partial \dot C}
=\frac{\partial [C(u)-C(u^{n-1})+C^(u^{n-1})]}{\partial \dot C}
=\frac{\partial [C(u)-C(u^{n-1})]}{\partial \dot C}+\frac{\partial C(u^{n-1})}{\partial \dot C}
\\
=\frac{\partial \Delta t[\dot C(u)]}{\partial \dot C}+0
=\Delta t
$$
